# Converting constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, type-conversion, constants, copy-constructor

Trying to compile the code:

```
class Foo
{
    public:
        Foo(Foo&){}
        Foo(int*){}
};

int main()
{
    int i = 2;
    Foo foo = &i;
    return 0;
}
```

Getting this:

```
prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
prog.cpp:11:16: error: no matching function for call to ‘Foo::Foo(Foo)’
prog.cpp:11:16: note: candidates are:
prog.cpp:5:9: note: Foo::Foo(int*)
prog.cpp:5:9: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Foo’ to ‘int*’
prog.cpp:4:9: note: Foo::Foo(Foo&)
prog.cpp:4:9: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Foo’ to ‘Foo&’
```

I expected that on the `Foo foo = &i` line should be called the `Foo(int*)` c-tor.

Why does the compiler try to find `Foo::Foo(Foo)` c-tor instead?

Why doesn't it just use the `Foo(int*)` c-tor which is present?

Why the code will DO compile when I add `const` to the parameter of the first c-tor?

Why the code will DO compile when I remove the firs c-tor completely?

Thanks!

Comment: I suspect you need `Foo(const Foo&){}`. Or `Foo foo(&i);`. This is [copy initialization](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/036.htm), so you need a valid copy constructor.

Comment: Just a note...the parameter to a copy constructor must be `const`

Comment: @CaptainObvlious I've noticed that if I add `const` the code will work compile. But anyway the 1-st c-tor is not called on line `Foo foo = &i`. So why changing it's signature does affect the code? Also is it stated somewhere in the standard that `.the parameter to a copy constructor must be const`? Thanks.

Comment: @Kolyunya it's called actually - albeit implicitly. Please see Joachim's answer.

Comment: I should qualify that with "to work as you are expecting". See section 12.8 - Copying and Moving objects

Comment: Why was one good answer deleted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first constructor is a copy constructor which *can not be used to copy from temporaries*. For this, you need to add `const`, so the signature becomes `Foo(const Foo&)`.

The following code also compiles (a proper call to the constructor taking an `int*`):

```
Foo foo(&i);
```

Your code creates a (temporary) object `Foo` on the right hand side of the assignment operator and then assigns this object (using the (missing) copy constructor) to `foo`.

The compiler typically generates a copy constructor for you automatically, which takes a const reference. But since you defined a constructor taking a `Foo&`, **the compiler doesn't generate such a copy constructor for you**. So removing your first constructor also makes the code compile.

Comment: The first ctor **is** a copy ctor. It just cannot be used to copy from temporaries. See `C++11 [class.copy]§2`; any and all of `X&`, `const X&`, `volatile X&` and `const volatile X&` are valid copy ctor parameters for class `X`.

Comment: @Angew Thanks for clarifying; I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: I find something interesting that MS VC8.0 compiler will remove the temporary object of Foo and use the '&i' to construct foo so copy constructor will not be called, no error throw out.Even I compile it on debug mode. @leemes

Answer (score 2):

It's because the the compiler already creates an instance of `Foo` with the expression `&i`. It then tries to copy that into the destination variable `foo`, but as you don't have a proper copy-constructor it will not work.

A proper copy-constructor would have the signature `Foo(const Foo&)`. Note the `const`.

Comment: Could you please tell me then why the code http://ideone.com/ipyEjB will call only the 2-nd c-tor?

Comment: @Kolyunya My guess: It compiles if it is allowed to do the copy. But the compiler sees that it's not necessary.

Comment: @Kolyunya copies can be elided, but the necessary copy constructors must be available at compilation time.

Comment: How about "appropriate" instead of "proper?" It's still a copy ctor.

Comment: @juanchopanza could you please explain me is the `Foo(const Foo&)` called on the line `Foo foo = &i;`? If yes why in the code ideone.com/ipyEjB the `Foo(const Foo&)` is not printed. If no, why is even needed?

Comment: @Kolyunya it isn't *called* because the copy is elided. But it must be available, due to the rules of the language, spelled out in the link in my first comment.

Comment: @juanchopanza the trick is that the `Foo(const Foo&){}` is for some reason NOT created automatically as it should when we add an _improper_ c-tor `Foo(Foo&){}`. Maybe it's stated somewhere in the standard...

Comment: @Kolyunya The compiler generates a copy ctor if the user doesn't declare any. The generated copy ctor uses `const &` if possible. You do declare a copy ctor (with a non-const non-volatile ref parameter), so no other copy ctor is generated.

Comment: @Kolyunya Bear in mind that `Foo f = &i;` and `Foo f(&i);` are **not** equivalent. The first one is actually equivalent to `Foo f(Foo(&i))`, that is, it calls the copy ctor to copy from a temporary. (The call can be elided, but must be possible).

Comment: @Angew thank you for an explanation. Could you please tell me what does it mean that the `copy c-tor can be elided`? Thank you!

Comment: @Kolyunya The *call* to the copy ctor can be elided. It means that the object will be constructed directly in the destination space instead of being contructed in a temp and copied to the destination. IOW, the semantics of `Foo f (Foo(&i));` becomes that of `Foo f(&i);` if the copy is elided. Search for "copy elision" for details. And because elision is always optional, the program must be legal in the full, non-elided form.

Answer (score 1):

```
Foo foo = &i;
```

This line creates a temporary `Foo` object with a parameter of `&I`. This is what the compiler returns the line into:

```
Foo foo = Foo(&i);
```

Then it will try to copy-construct the temporary which it can't do because the constructor you created `Foo(Foo&)` overrides the copy-constructor. Add the following constructor to your code for it to work:

```
Foo(Foo const& other) {}
```

Answer (score -3):

Foo foo = &i will not do what you think, try Foo foo=Foo(&i)

Comment: Assigning a pointer to a non-pointer variable won't work either.

Comment: Looks like you might get a badge today ;)

Comment: You could have tried it yourself and seen that it does not work.